# How to execute shell cmd (python) using php and print all constant-updated outputs?

Tags: php, python, linux, shell

I am pretty new to php actually. So here's the thing:
I want to make a simple web-shell for the well-known youtube-dl, so I made a simple webpage and a simple php page, trying to use php to execute the youtube-dl and display all the outputs to the browser.

I've try the `command` thing and escapeshellcmd(), both of them can output the very first few lines of constant-updating outputs from the youtube-dl (and they work well with some other cmd like "ls"), but it seems that when it get the first line, the python script just stop, no more updates, and there is also no downloaded video file on my server.

BTW, it's all on Ubuntu 14 LTS.

So far, I have tried these:

```
    <?php
    $command = shell_exec('youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z456k6yBeo0');
    echo "<pre>$command</pre>";
    ?>
```

and

```
    <?php
    echo `youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z456k6yBeo0`
    >
```

and

```
    <?php
    $command = escapeshellcmd('youtube-dl https://www.youtube.co/watch?v=z456k6yBeo0');
    $output = shell_exec($command);
    echo $output;
    ?>
```

Both of them work well with "ls",but not working well with youtube-dl

Comment: im fairly certain this has nothing to do with python ... further without an actual code example you are extremely unlikely to get any answers let alone one that solves your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've managed to solve the problem. @zahyur is right, It's about permission. Since I am used to using root to manage my server,there wouldn't be any problem while I execute the command from shell. But server needs extra permission to execute the command to write things in the directory.

The solution is to build a new directory and give it write access, execute the command in that directory and there will be no problems.

Answer (score 2):

Try the [`shell_exec` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php):

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('ls -lart');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: link only answers are frowned upon ... also the official language is english +1 all the same as I *think* this is the right answer

Comment: the `` and escapeshellcmd() actually work well when using ls ,just like the shell_exec(). But still cannot output all the printings from youtube-dl, and not getting the video downloaded

Answer (score 1):

This example from your question works for me:

```
<?php
    $command = escapeshellcmd('youtube-dl https://www.youtube.co/watch?v=z456k6yBeo0');
    $output = shell_exec($command);
    echo $output;
```

What is your version of PHP? Mine is 5.5.9.

You may also use proc_open like this (We're probably missing the error here, so try this updated version):

```
<?php
$descriptorspec = array(0 => array("pipe", "w"), 2 => array('file', '/tmp/youtube-dl-errors',  'a'));
$command = escapeshellcmd('youtube-dl https://www.youtube.co/watch?v=z456k6yBeo0');
$handle = proc_open($command, $descriptorspec, $pipes);
echo stream_get_contents($pipes[0]);
echo file_get_contents('/tmp/youtube-dl-errors');
proc_close($handle);
```

You may also use exec, which gives you the exit status:

```
<?php
$cmd = 'youtube-dl https://www.youtube.co/watch?v=z456k6yBeo0';
exec(escapeshellcmd($cmd), $output, $status);
if ($status) echo "Exec command failed.";
else echo var_dump($output);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but the escapeshellcmd printed only `[generic] watch?v=z456k6yBeo0: Requesting header [redirect] Following redirect to https://www.youtube.com/watch?gl=CO&v=z456k6yBeo0&hl=es-419 [youtube] z456k6yBeo0: Downloading webpage [youtube] z456k6yBeo0: Extracting video information [youtube] z456k6yBeo0: Downloading DASH manifest ` to the page and stopped, no more updates, and I didnt see the downloaded video on my server. Mine is also 5.5.9.

Comment: Is it working when executed directly from your shell?
Do your script has write access to its current directory? If not, or you want to use different directory anyway, you can add 4th parameter to proc_open with different  path for initial working directory:
    $handle = proc_open($command, array(array("pipe", "w")), $pipes, 'absolute_path_to_writable_directory');

Comment: Yes I've used youtube-dl many times so I'm sure it works on my shell. I will try to dig it in a few days to see if there is any problem with it.